# Actionscript 3.0 -> How to override a protected method from UIComponent

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I want to create a custom button in ActionScript.

This is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.controls.Alert;

import spark.components.Button;

public class BookViewButton extends Button
{
    public function BookViewButton()
    {
        super();
    }
    override protected function mouseOver(event:MouseEvent,increase:int,newImageSource:String):void{
        Alert.show("mouseOver for new class works");
    }
}
```

But Adobe Flash Builder signals the method overriding line as an error.

I tried to change the new method signature so that it would match exactly, like this: (I thought the error might be because I was adding extra parameters to the `mouseOver` function so Flex might have not recognized it as an overriding)

```
        override protected function mouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
        Alert.show("mouseOver for new class works");
    }
```

But still it doesn't work. Same little red exclamation mark comes up to signal a mistake.

I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What SDK version do you use if you have `mouseOver()` method in Spark `Button` hierarchy?

Spark button has `mouseEventHandler()` method to override:

```
override protected function mouseEventHandler(event:Event):void
{
    super.mouseEventHandler(event);
    var mouseEvent:MouseEvent = event as MouseEvent;
    if (event.type == MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER)
    {
        // My roll over logic here
    }
}
```

And it is better to post the error text which IDE gives you. To copy it just open `Problems` view in Flash Builder, found your error message and copy it via context menu.

Comment: But please explain me where did you found `mouseOver()` method to override?

Comment: I didn't actually find it anywhere I think. I sort of guessed there should be some method like that. Or maybe I misread some info. I don't know. It's 04:30 a.m. where I live. That should partly explain that. =)

Comment: Hmm.. If I understand you correctly, you are calling the superclass' eventHandler and *then* adding extra logic to that?

Comment: Right. We should't break default behavior.

Comment: Also, I think it's important to say that if you just want to use the mouse over event, don't extend the component, composite it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `override` here because the base class `Button` does not have a method `mouseOver` to override.

If you remove the override keyword it should work fine. That said, you'll need to actually add a listener for your function for it to be called when you mouse over. Like this:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import spark.components.Button;

public class BookViewButton extends Button
{
    public function BookViewButton()
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, _mouseOver);
    }

    private function _mouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Alert.show("mouseOver for new class works");
    }
}
```

---

Info on `super();`

There's no need to call super in the constructor of an extending class, unless there are arguments that you want to parse. Example.

```
package
{
    public class A extends Object
    {
        public function A()
        {
            trace("A");
        }
    }
}
```

And the extending class:

```
package
{
    public class B extends A
    {
        public function B()
        {
            trace("B");
        }
    }
}
```

If we do:

```
var thing:B = new B();
```

You will have the output:

```
A
B
```

However, if you wanted arguments for your constructor, you would need to parse them up to the constructor of the class you're extending using `super()`. Like so:

```
public class A extends Object
{
    public function A(arg:String)
    {
        trace(arg);
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public function B(arg:String)
    {
        super(arg);
    }
}
```

Now this will output "asdf":

```
var thing:B = new B("asdf");
```

Comment: Hmmm That makes sense. But should I really remove the call to the superclass constructor (`super()`) like you did in your code?

Comment: Thanks for going into the trouble of writing all that. I just wondered because, since I'm basically extending the basic `Button` class, I should call the superclass constructor and *then* create extra behaviour for my custom button. But apparently not. Thanks.

Comment: Nah, the superclass constructor will be called without needing super() :)